# Writing Function but Argument is too long

Tags: excel, function

I am trying to write a function, but the problem is that my argument is too long.

```
=IF(G7=1,"Parfaite",IF(G7>0.87,"Forte",IF(G7>0.75,"Moyenne",IF(G7>0.5,"Faible",IF(G7<0.5,"Nulle",IF(G7>-0.5,"Nulle",IF(G7>-0.75,"Faible",IF(G7>0,87,"Moyenne",IF(G7>-1,"Forte",IF(G7=-1,"Parfaite","ERREURE"))))))))))`
```

Is there anyway I can shorten this or make it into two functions?

Comment: Wow, Is this an Excel function?

Comment: Could you reformat the code to get it more human readable?

Comment: Excel function separator can change if there is a conflict with the decimal separator of your OS.  French, for instance, is using `,` as the decimal separator which cause Excel to use `;` as the function seperator.  You might want to check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `,` in the following section between `0` and `87`.

```
IF(G7>0,87,"Moyenne"
```

I replaced the comma with a period `.` assuming you wanted to compare `G7` with `0.87` and this works.

`=IF(G7=1,"Parfaite",IF(G7>0.87,"Forte",IF(G7>0.75,"Moyenne",IF(G7>0.5,"Faible",IF(G7<0.5,"Nulle",IF(G7>-0.5,"Nulle",IF(G7>-0.75,"Faible",IF(G7>0.87,"Moyenne",IF(G7>-1,"Forte",IF(G7=-1,"Parfaite","ERREURE"))))))))))`

#### Screenshot of Formula working

[image]
If not, fix that `,`. That's why you are getting the `Too many arguments` error. Because the `,` is treating `0` and `87` and 2 separate paramaters.

Answer (score 1):

`OR()` makes your formula a lot shorter:

```
IF(OR(G7=1,G7=-1)"Parfaite",IF(OR(G7>0.87,G7>-1),"Forte",IF(OR(G7>0.75,0.87),"Moyenne",IF(OR(G7>0.5,G7>-0.75),"Faible",IF(OR(G7<0.5,G7>-0.5),"Nulle","ERREURE")))))
```